# Ruby on Rails - translating form input arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, internationalization

I have one form and one table showing the results of the values added to the form. When I started translating the form I put the following code in the table headers:

```
<th> <%= t :kilometers %> </th>
```

The result after this change was "Kilometers", although I don't have such a value in the en.yml file, which is perfect for me.

Since I am using bootstrap and need to put a translated attribute to the input tag. I tried to do it in the same way in order to acheive the same result as the above one:

```
<%= f.text_field :kilometers, placeholder: I18n.t(:kilometers) %>
```

But now rails tells me "translation missing".

Could you please tell me how can I acheive the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an entry to your en.yml file. In the table header you just don't see the warning but it *is* there. If you hover over the text in your `th`, you will see:

> translation missing: en.kilometers

Comment: Yes, I know. But I was wondering why should I do that since it is working with the table, but not with the attribute?

Comment: @niki4ko It's not working in the table! The warning is added in the title attribute of a `span`, that's why you don't see it, but the warning *is* there. You can't add a span tag inside a `text_field`, that's why you *do* see it in the text field. The only solution is to add an entry for kilometers to en.yml.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Yes, it is not working. Actually that was my question - what is actually happening. Thank you very much! It is very clear now!